# Licensing a spring boot application inside an AMI

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-ami, aws-marketplace

Say we have a standalone spring boot application which we are going to distribute by creating an AMI and sharing on the AWS marketplace. Since the jar is available inside the AMI, I want to stop a user from buying the AMI on the marketplace and then redistributing my jar.

This is my current implementation plan for this:

1. When building the jar, I bundle a blank file (ex: test.abc) with the jar
2. When user starts jar for the first time, I check if this file is blank, if it is, then I write the mac address of the current machine into the file
3. Validate the file to check if the mac address on the file is same as the mac address of the machine

There will also need to be a way of "hiding" the file `test.abc` from the user so he/she cannot rebundle the jar with another blank `test.abc`.

Is there a better/industrial standard of meeting this requirement?

Comment: Mac addresses can be forged.  [Check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4231031/how-to-implement-a-simple-licensing-scheme) for the start of a trail that will suggest a better methodology.

Comment: @mcfinnigan Understood. Other than the workaround with a forged MAC address is there anything that you think is fundamentally wrong with this approach?

Comment: Yes, the approach of using local secrets as a source of trust is fundamentally flawed.

Comment: @mcfinnigan is it possible for you to recommend a better way of meeting this requirement? With the requirement being to prevent a user from basically copying my jar file and using on a separate system.. I understand there is no foolproof method and someone will always find a way but which do you think is best?